# Ir a una URL predeterminada en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Buen día! Estoy tratando que cuando pongo una URL en mi navegador y el usuario esté logeado vaya a esa URL.

Actualmente tengo esto en el AppComponent.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
     if (token){
       sessionStorage.setItem('user', localStorage.getItem('user'));
       sessionStorage.setItem('token', localStorage.getItem('token'));
      this.navigator.goToIndex();
     }else{
this.navigator.goToLogin('');
     }
  }
```

Cuestión, es poco práctico porque si quiero ir a otra URL diferente para usuarios logeados, te deja en el INDEX...
Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Quizá debas usar [`this.router.navigate(..)`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate). Además, creo que `ngOnInit` no es un buen sitio donde poner este tipo de código, quizá el constructor sea el lugar más adecuado o, dependiendo de la aplicación implementar [`CanActivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que la mejor solución para tu problema es implementar [`CanActivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) en tu ruta, cambiando esto en ella:

```
{ path: 'tu_ruta', component: AppComponent, canActivate: [ SesionGuard ] },
```

Tras lo cual deberemos generar `SesionGuard` de la siguiente manera:

```
ng generate guard sesion-guard
```

Implementando esto en el código:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class SesionGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        /* Comprobamos si has iniciado sesión */
        if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
            /* Si tenemos iniciada la sesión entonces permitimos el acceso */
            return true;
        }
        /* En caso contrario redirigimos a la página de inicio de sesión */
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```